# What does it mean in rails when data has [FILTERED] next to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I havn't worked with rails in a while but I have a table called portions which has a column freshvegetable which is an integer. Whenever I go into rails console to look at the values in the portion table, freshvegetable has a value [FILTERED]. What exactly does that mean?

edit: this is what I have in filter_parameter_logging.rb

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :passw, :secret, :token, :_key, :crypt, :salt, :certificate, :otp, :ssn
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check is it filtered in config/application file or in any initializers file?
line would look like

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:freshvegetable]
```

Comment: I've added above what I have in filter_parameter_logging.rb but that field is not there